# Тестирование на Единичный корень (unit root)

Tags: математика, r, статистика, анализ-данных, статический-анализ

При при проверке на наличие единичного корня (ADF-test) для одного из рядов по информационному критерию Акайка  были выбраны результаты теста с 4 лагами (ряд стационарный), по критерию Шварца с лагом 3 (ряд нестационарный). Как правильно тогда интерпретировать результат, если при изменении количества лагов наблюдается существееное различие в результатах?  Если в дальнейшем используется VAR c лагом 3, то и ADF-test необходимо рассматривать с 3 лагами (вне зависимости от информационных критериев).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, теоретически известно, что  для  моделей авторегрессии  критерий AIC склонен к переоценке порядка модели, а BIC такого недостатка лишен. Но какой критерий выбрать - это решать вам, ибо формального ответа на этот вопрос нет.

Но сам вопрос мне не совсем понятен. ADF-test используется для ответа на вопрос, стационарен ли ряд. Если нет -  берем разности, и повторяем процедуру. Таким образом определеяем уровень интегрируемости ряда.

Если нам надо строить модель -  строим ее, даже если она не стационарна. Например ARIMA. В ней один параметр мы определили - I. Остальные надо как-то подобрать (например по анализу коррелограмм), но у нас все равно может оказаться несколько моделей. Строим их. А потом из них хотим выбрать лучшую. Используя для этого либо R-квадрат и его модификации, либо AIC,  BIC, HQ, либо другие тесты.

Ну прекрасно. Каким боком результат ADF-test к интерпретации результата?

И что означает фраза "Если в дальнейшем используется VAR c лагом 3, то и ADF-test необходимо рассматривать с 3 лагами" если ADF-test  используется ДО построения модели?

Но даже если вы вдруг ADF-test решили использовать для анализа остатков регрессионных моделей, то и тогда связь (логика) в вашем вопросе остается непонятной.

Comment: Так с критериями то все понятно, критерий Шварца имеет большее фундаментальное обоснование и бла бла бла. Но результаты реально от количество лагов существенно зависят, а учитывая, что критерий мы выбираем самостоятельно, мы можем подгонять результаты под стационарность и нестационарность. Хотелось бы притянуть хоть какое-то обоснование выбранного количества лагов (например , связь с var).

Comment: Про описание теста adf и  ARIMA, извините не совсем поняла, зачем это вставлено.

Comment: И вопрос, да, из разряда не методологии, а естественнонаучного любопытства: как можно судить о достоверности  и интерпретировать результаты adf test, если по разным информационным критериям , он то стационарен , то нет

Comment: Давайте не все сразу. "Как можно судить о достоверности и интерпретировать результаты adf test, если по разным информационным критериям , он то стационарен, то нет". Стоп. Adf-test говорит только о том, стационарен ли ряд или нет и отношения к моделям не имеют. Причем тут информационные критерии, которые оценивают (сравнивают)  разные модели? Не мешайте все в кучу!

Comment: Я,конечно, сомневаюсь в своей адекватности, но кажется тут путаница между df (стандартный тест Дикки- Фуллера) и adf (расширенный тест Д-Ф, в котором можно выбирать количество лагов: https://en-wikipedia-org.turbopages.org/s/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test ).  По крайней мере Eviews дает возможность автоматически оценить его качество на основе инфокритериев, все равно же тест основан на модели (https://eviews.com/help/helpintro.html#page/content%2Fadvtimeser-Unit_Root_Testing.html%23ww185348). Для наглядности прикрепила в вопросе скрин.

Comment: Я не знаю, как работает eViews, но расширенный D-F тест в Python statsmodels позволяет задать  наличие-отсутствие константы сдвига,  параметра тренда, вид информационного критерия и максимальное количество лагов.  Но он никак не строит саму модель. Он лишь подсказывает, какой лаг лучше избрать.  И да, при разных инф.критериях результаты будут отличаться.  Но вообще-то для приведения ряда к стационарному виду могут применяться и другие подходы - преобразования Бокса-Кокса, логарифмированием и т.д.  Но к собственно построению модели и их сравнению - это имеет опосредственное отношение.

Comment: Поняла теперь, что Вас так смущает в вопросе - слово "модель" (поправила, спасибо). Под ним подразумевался авторегрессионный процесс, на котором и базируется проведение теста. Да, все эти стандартные параметры тоже доступны для выбора в указанной программе. То есть агрегируя: 1) результаты adf теста варьируются в зависимости от количества лагов, принятие решение остется на совести автора (формального подхода нет); 2) это решение о стационарности (нестационарности) не зависит от дальнейшего использования данных, так как тест проводится до построения других моделей.

Comment: Надеюсь, я Вас правильно поняла и понятно описала )

Comment: Примерно правильно :-) Только я ошибся в последнем ответе. Вместо слова "лаг выбрать" надо читать "степень интегрированности  выбрать" -  практически параметр I ( или в некоторых источниках его обозначают d - "differences")